# Some Unicode Charactors are Omitted In MYSQL Full Text Search

Tags: mysql, unicode, full-text-search

The **test_table** has one row and the value in the **content** column (*mediumtext, utf8_general_ci*) is

```
₩₱₩₱₩₱ 中国人
```

This query returns 1 result (as expected)

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE  MATCH(content) AGAINST ('中国人' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This query returns 0 results (not as expected)

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE  MATCH(content) AGAINST ('₩₱₩₱₩₱' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Anyone has any idea on why the second query doesn't work?

Comment: Add some more rows -- make sure that the thing you are searching for is in less than 50% of the rows.  Does it still fail?  WHat version of MySQL?  Which engine?

Comment: @RickJames It didn't work (Mariadb 10.2 - InnoDB). It looks like currency symbols ($, ₩, ₱) are ommited in full text search.

Comment: The sample code is looking for a "word" with 6 letters:  `'₩₱₩₱₩₱'`.   It seems unlikely that any document in the world would contain that, other than this Q&A.